# subtract columns from 2 files and output to new files

Tags: bash, awk

I have 2 files in below formats.

```
File1_Stored.txt
ABC:100, 83
ABC:84, 53
ABC:14, 1222

File2_Stored.txt
ABC:100 , 83
ABC:84 , 1553
ABC:524 , 2626
```

I am trying to get the 3rd file in below format. So, whenever difference  is 0 it shouldnt appear but if the diffence is not 0 then it should appear like

```
Value , File1 Value , File2 Value , Difference
----------------------------------------------
ABC:84,  53          ,1553         , -1500
ABC:14,  1222        , 0           , 1222
ABC:524, 0           ,2626         ,-2626
```

I tried doing it using awk to get the difference but it failing

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;B[$1]=$2}{$2-=A[$1]}1' File1_Stored.txt  File2_Stored.txt
```

Any help is much appriciated.

Regards,

Comment: Try this [link](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/150175-need-help-subtract-columns-2-files-output-new-file.html)

Comment: already tried .

Comment: your example output doesn't seem to match your rule description. Please clarify your Q. How does the program  differentiate between and ABC on line 1 and line 3. Why are the 4 columns of output, and only 2 columns of input (after the ABC:). ? Good luck.

Comment: ABC:84 is one enttity , when output is Entity , File1 value , File2 value , Difference

Comment: provide textual description of how you generate the result set from the given inputs; add said description to your question

Comment: wrt `whenever difference is 0` - different between what and what?

Comment: Done . Thanks for pointing that .

Comment: @Ed Morton difference for ABC:84 in file1 and file2 which is 53

Comment: So - the difference between the column 2 values for each column 1 in each file where the columns are separated by "optional-space comma optional-space" strings?

Comment: it is sep by comma

Comment: That's not what your posted sample input/output shows. [edit] the example in your question to be truly representative of your real data if it currently isn't so we're not helping you solve a problem you don't have. Right now a solution relying on spaces between fields could produce the expected output from your sample input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS="[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"
    OFS=","
    print "Value", "File1 Value", "File2 Value", "Difference"
}
NR==FNR {
    a[$1] = $2
    next
}
{
    diff = a[$1] - $2
    if ( diff != 0 ) {
        print $1, a[$1]+0, $2, diff
    }
    delete a[$1]
}
END {
    for (key in a) {
        print key, a[key], 0, 0
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
Value,File1 Value,File2 Value,Difference
ABC:84,53,1553,-1500
ABC:524,0,2626,-2626
ABC:14,1222,0,0
```

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F' *, *' 'BEGIN{ fmt="%s,  %d,  %d,  %d\n" }   # output format
               NR==FNR{ a[$1]=$2; next }
               {   
                   d=a[$1]-$2;   # difference
                   if ($1 in a && d==0) { delete a[$1]; next }; 
                   printf fmt, $1,a[$1]+0,$2,a[$1]-$2; delete a[$1] 
               }
               END{ 
                   for(i in a) printf fmt, i,a[i],0,a[i];  # check for unmatched items
               }' file1 file2
```

The output:

```
ABC:84,  53,  1553,  -1500
ABC:524,  0,  2626,  -2626
ABC:14,  1222,  0,  1222
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` script:

```
$ cat file.awk
BEGIN { FS=" *, *" }
NR==FNR { A[$1]=$2 ;      B[$1]=0  ; next }
        { A[$1]=A[$1]+0 ; B[$1]=$2 }
END {
for (x in A)
    { diff=A[x]-B[x]
      if (diff!=0) { printf "%s,%s,%s,%s\n",x,A[x],B[x],diff }
    }
}
```

- `BEGIN { FS=" *, *" }` : define input field separator as a) zero or more spaces plus b) a comma plus c) zero or more spaces
- `NR==FNR` : for first file ...
- `A[$1]=$2` : store values in array `A` and ...
- `B[$1]=0` : zero out an associated entry in the `B` array
- `{ A[$1]=A[$1]+0...` : for second file add zero to associated `A` array (this has the effect of creating a new `A` array item if it doesn't already exist), then store current record value in array `B`
- at this point we should have entries in both arrays for all possible key values
- `END {...}` : after processing the input files has completed ...
- `for (x in A)` : loop through indexes of array `A`
- `diff=...` : find the difference between corresponding array values
- `if (diff!=0) ...` : if our difference is not zero then print the results

Script in action:

```
$ awk -f file.awk  File1_Stored.txt  File2_Stored.txt
ABC:524,0,2626,-2626
ABC:14,1222,0,1222
ABC:84,53,1553,-1500
```